Is fashion Illustration Haram?
I am a recent revert as of June 2024. I am an artist and wish to go into fashion design to bring modest clothing options to my area. The course I plan to take will want to have me drawing rough human figures, with loose and artistic methods of showing different fabrics and how they sit. Is there a way to do this without it being haram?
Thank you for taking the time to answer.

After some more research I see that some beliefs are that living beings cannot be drawn in detail, but if the detail in the figure itself is marred, and just shows the clothing on the model would that be permissible?

It is not Haram as far as I could explain, at least in Shia Perspective where drawing figures are not problematic these days when it is done with good faith. (Maybe refer to Is there any problem in the art of sculpting and painting? from islamQuest website, or to here for different related ideas of Shia scholars.)
